# How do I download Youtube videos for offline viewing on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, youtube

I have just tried 28 different apps that claim to download youtube videos for offline viewing/listening, including Instapaper and Pocket.

None of them do it; they all expect there to be an internet connection.

Is there just .... 1 app .... that works?

Answer (score 3):

YouTube currently offers this within their app if you pay the premium of $9.99 USD per month for what they call [YouTube Red](https://www.youtube.com/red)

Key Features according to their marketing is:

- YouTube Music
- Ad free & **offline video**
- Orginal Shows

Answer (score 0):

You could try FinalTube2 Free

https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/finaltube2/id843407334?mt=8

I have try it and it is works.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Could you expand your answer to include more details on the app, preferably with instructions on *how* to use the app to download YouTube videos?

Answer (score -1):

As pointed out, this is for macOS, not iOS...

Recently I have had good results with [Bigasoft Video Downloader](http://www.bigasoft.com/video-downloader-pro-mac.html) ... the non-"pro" free version works great (but cannot download multiple videos unattended)

Comment: Could you expand your answer to include more details on the app, preferably with instructions on how to use the app to download YouTube videos?

Comment: The asker requested software that will work _on their iOS device_. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this looks like it's for traditional macs/pc's.